# How to delete a Excel row data in such case

Tags: excel, vba, row, delete-row

I have a Excel data like below:

```
----|----|----|--
      A         B
----|----|----|--
      C    D
----|----|----|--
      B    A
----|----|----|--
```

and In my need The first row " A B " is equal to the third row " B A ",  I just want to keep only one of them.  How to remove the other one ,THx

Comment: So, you need to remove rows that have duplicate information (that may appear in any order)?  Does it matter which row you keep? If so, how do you know which should stay and which should go?  (♪ ♫ Come on and let me know ♪ ♫ )

Comment: @BruceWayne if it stays it will be trouble, but if it goes...Any body got a peanut.  Dang mixed up my quotes.

Comment: The sheet may contain about 2W+ rows , I just want to keep only one row ,no matter " A B " or " B A " , there may be thousand of the case (like " A B " ----" B A " ,or  " L N " ----" N  L " . I tried to use VBA to deal with that,buy failed

Answer (score 0):

I could test and revise the code as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MAIN()
    Dim dataRng As Range, col As Range, cell As Range

    With Worksheets("myWorksheetName") '<--| change "myWorksheetName" to your actual worksheet name
        With .UsedRange
            Set dataRng = .Cells
            With .Offset(1, .Columns.Count + 1).Resize(.Columns.Count, .Rows.Count)
                .Value = Application.Transpose(dataRng.Value)
                For Each col In .Columns
                    col.Sort key1:=col.Cells(1, 1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
                    col.Cells(1, 1).Offset(-1) = Replace("|" & Join(Application.Transpose(col.Value), "|") & "|", "||", "")
                Next col

                For Each cell In .Rows(1).Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1).Cells
                    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Rows(1).Offset(-1).Resize(, cell.Column - .Columns(1).Column), cell.Value) > 0 Then .Offset(, -1).Cells(cell.Column - .Columns(1).Column, 1) = 1
                Next cell
                .Offset(-1).Resize(.Rows.Count + 1).ClearContents
            End With

            With .Resize(, .Columns.Count + 1)
                .AutoFilter Field:=.Columns.Count, Criteria1:=1
                .Resize(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: when the script run to the 7th line it pop up an error like " error 1004"

Comment: I don't have line numbers, type in the line that throws the error along with the error number and description.

Comment: this line " With .Offset(1, .Columns.Count + 1).Resize(.Columns.Count, .Rows.Count) " , the error is  " Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" " ,I had replaced the worksheet name